Use of relational operator dynamically in prepared statement
select * from tableA where date > 12/8/2012
select * from tableA where date ? ?
dateselect can be any of these operator dynamically value is sent in the function <,>,=
gMStmt.setString(1,dateselect); gMStmt.setDate(2, date);

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

If I concate with string then I am getting sql injection security issue. Tool CodeQL Rule ID java/sql-injection Query View source Description If a database query is built using string concatenation, and the components of the concatenation include user input, a user is likely to be able to run malicious database queries. This applies to various database query languages, including SQL and the Java Persistence Query Language.
Please help to resolve the issue.
